Integral closure in characteristic 0
Let A be a Noetherian domain of characteristic 0, K be its field of fractions. Is the integral closure of A in K always finitely generated as A-module?

Didn't Nagata give a Krull dimension three counterexample to this?

There is an example on the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata_ring. Since there is no reference, it is hard to determine the original source of the example (I have not found it in Nagata's book), but it seems to work. The example is as follows: take the subring $R \subset k[x_1, x_2, \dots]$ generated by $x_1^2, x_1^3, x_2^2, x_2^3, x_3^2, x_3^3, \dots$, and attach inverses to all elements that are not in one of the following ideals: $(x_1), (x_2), \dots$. Let the resulting ring be $S$. Then $S$ is a Noetherian $1$-dimensional domain that is not N-1, since the integral closure is (localization of) $k[x_1, x_2, \dots]$.
P.S.: Welcome to MathOverflow, Prof. Drozd :)

This is Example 1 in Hochster's "Non-openness of loci in Noetherian rings."
